# shake - how to copy all contents of a directory

Tags: shake-build-system

I want to use shake for regression testing and I have to set up the test directory. I would like to copy a directory with fonts into the test directory and included a `need` on the target directory and then copy the files but my code gives the error:

```
Probably due to calling 'need' on a directory. Shake only permits 'need' on files.
```

I tried to get `needs` on the single files, but do not succeed. I have

```
        fontFiles1 <- getDirectoryFiles (templatesD</>"et-book" ) ["/**/*"]
        need $ map (\f -> staticD</>"et-book"</>f) fontFiles1
```

and then :

```
  (staticD</>"et-book/**") %> \out ->
        copyFileChanged  (replaceDirectory out (templatesD</>"et-book")) out
```

but this does not include all the subdirectories under `et-book`.

What is the right way to do this? Should I just copy all directory content over (with e.g. System.Path from fsutils)?

Answer (score 1):

This answer is correct in spirit, so I suspect there are just a few details that are slightly wrong:

- Does `fontFiles1` contain the complete list of files? My guess is the pattern should be `**`, and that the leading `/` is confusing things. Either way, `**` would be simpler and more future proof.
- The `replaceDirectory` replaces all directory components, so if you have `static/et-book/foo/bar.txt`, then you are going to copy from `templates/et-book/bar.txt`. Assuming you know `staticD` is always exactly one directory component, then `templatesD</>dropDirectory1 out` would work as a source location.

The pattern of copying a directory is pretty common, so I probably will add a helper function to make it easier in a future version. A ticket and discussion about that is happening on the [Shake bug tracker](https://github.com/ndmitchell/shake/issues/263).

Comment: Thank you, it is good to know that it is ok in principle and I have just to work out the details with more attention. Thanks for adding a function... (by the way, I looked at the discussion of the bug tracker and took some inspiration from there, but I could not understanding the approach on simple reading).